# Bash function to process all dotfiles in a directory excluding directories

Tags: bash, grep, find, bash-function

I am looking to create a bash function to filter all the dotfiles (no directories) in a selected directory. I only need the file name, not the full path.

For the moment, i only have this command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0
```

which prints all the files excluding the dirs. Now i still have to exclude the non-dotfiles. So i've try to pipe the output to grep, like so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep "^\."
```

and it didn't seem to work. ->

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Do you guys have an elegant solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: try changing your command to find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -a "^\."

Comment: did you want only the filenames startswith dot?

Comment: Thanks! It works if i run the command directly within the directory. But what i want to do is to be able to assign that command a path in which to run the search...
Something like:
find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -a "^\."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only dot-files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -printf '%f\0'
```

The test `-name '.*'` selects dot files.  Since `-name` accepts globs, `.` means a literal period and `*` means any number of any character.

The action `-printf '%f\0'` will print NUL-separated filenames without the path.

If your name selection criteria becomes more complex, find also offers `-regex` which selects files based on regular expressions.  GNU find understands several different dialects of regular expression.  These can be selected with `-regextype`.  Supported dialects include `emacs` (default), `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep`, and `posix-extended`.

#### Mac OSX or other BSD System

BSD `find` does not offer `-printf`.  In its place, try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -exec basename {} \;
```

Note that this will be safe all file names, even those containing difficult characters such as blanks, tabs or newlines.

#### Putting the dot files into a bash array

If you want to get all dot files and directories into an array, it is simple:

```
all=(.*).
```

That is safe for all file names.

If you want to get only regular files, not directories, then use bash:

```
a=(); while IFS= read -r -d ''; do a+=("$(basename "$REPLY")"); done < <( find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -print0 )
```

This is also safe for all file names.

Comment: The OP mentioned only needing the file name, not the full path. You could achieve that by using `-printf '%f\0'` instead of `-print0`.

Comment: I tried your -printf solution and looks like `find` command doesn't know -printf:
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @JeanmichelCote OK.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @JeanmichelCote Answer updated with something that should be OSX (BSD) compatible.  Also, ignore the part about `-regextype` as the OSX find does not support it.

Comment: @John1024 Works fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83648/discussion-between-jeanmichel-cote-and-john1024).

Answer (score 1):

Get all the hidden files, with the full paths

```
find . -type f -name '.*'
```

Get just the filenames of the hidden files:

```
for f in `find . -type f -name '.*'`; do basename "$f"; done
```

Because file names can contain white space (blanks, tabs, newlines), however, it is safer to use:

```
find . -type f -name '.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do basename "$f"; done
```

Comment: Hum, this does not work. It freezes the shell and never return anything.

Comment: The freezing is likely because the test `-maxdepth 1` is missing so `find` searches the whole directory tree.

Comment: Works fine now. I got the best results from this answer and adding the -maxdepth 1 option.

On top of this, i can use the `$HOME` variable instead of the `.`.

But i read somewhere that it is bad practice, securitywise, to do a search with `.*`.

Comment: @user2182349 I added to your answer a version of the loop approach that is safe for all file names.  (If you don't like it, feel free to revert.)

Comment: @John1024 - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use bash globbing/pattern matching:

```
for f in .[^.]*; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f"
done
```

`[^.]` is a negating expression to avoid matching `.` (current working directory) or `..` (parent directory).